# jquery mobile datepicker not working o clicking textbox

Tags: jquery, html, datepicker

Hi I am new to jQuerymobile.I am trying to implement a date picker which needs to come as a popup onclicking the text box.But onSelect is not working and no click action is taking place.
The code is

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<!-- Need to get a proper redirect hooked up. Blech. -->



<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>RideMix</title>
<link rel="stylesheet"  href="jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="demos/_assets/favicon.ico">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,700">


<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.ui.datepicker.mobile.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothnes/jquery-ui.css" />   
<script src="jquery.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

<script>
    $( document ).on( "pageshow", function(){
        $( "p.message" ).hide().delay( 1500 ).show( "fast" );
    });
</script>
 <script>
$(function() {
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
$( "#datepicker1" ).datepicker();

}); 
</script>
```

```
<div class="productimage">  

                <input data-theme="c" type="search" name="search" id="search-basic" value="" placeholder="Leaving from"/>
                <input data-theme="c" type="search" name="search" id="search-basic" value="" placeholder="Going to"/>
                <p>&nbsp</p>
                <div class="ui-bar ui-bar-b datetime">
                <h3 class="">Date and time </h3>
                </div>
                <div style="width:90%;">
                <br />
                <label>From Date</label>
                <input type="date" name="date" id="datepicker" value=""  />
                <label>To Date</label>
                <input type="date" name="date" id="datepicker" value=""  />

                </div>  
                    <p>&nbsp</p>
                <a href="#" data-transition="fade" data-role="button" data-theme="b"  style="width:70%;margin:auto">Next Step</a>
        </div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you're using jquery mobile only <input type="text" data-role="date"> would be enough if I remember correctly. Edit; nevermind, I used that using another plugin. Try to see if copy-pasting the code from http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/ works. Could be something else. Or take a look at http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.0a4.1/experiments/ui-datepicker/

Comment: I followed the methods from these references..but still I am not able to ..maybe some conflict issues with jquery version

Answer (score 1):

Try:

- changing the `input type="text"`
- specify the date format when initializing the datepicker
- assign unique `id`s to your `input` fields

Here's an example:

```js
$(function() {
  $("#datepicker-from").datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'yy-MM-dd'
  });
  $("#datepicker-to").datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'yy-MM-dd'
  });
});
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,700">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
<div class="productimage">
  <div class="ui-bar ui-bar-b datetime">
    <h3 class="">Date and time </h3>
  </div>
  <div style="width:90%;">
    <br />
    <label>From Date</label>
    <input type="text" name="date-from" id="datepicker-from" value="" />
    <label>To Date</label>
    <input type="text" name="date-to" id="datepicker-to" value="" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @rphv..Thank you for the effort.But still the code is not working for me.:(

Comment: @AmitNair sorry to hear that - does the code snippet above work for you when you click "Run code snippet?" Do you see any errors in the console?

Comment: Yes the snippet is working pefectly..great work..but don't why it is not working in my application..No errors are shown in the console..:(

Comment: My first thought is to look at the css and js files included in the header - maybe there's a conflict there, or maybe the datepicker css is being overridden somehow. Can you provide any more information? What happens when you click on the date fields? What browser/version/OS are you using? Does the rest of your application work OK? Does the snippet above work on your local machine?

Comment: Ya...Nothing is happening on clicking the textfield..and no errors are also not showning in console..I am running the app in windows7 OS,Chrome browser...and rest of the application featuring jquery mobile seems to be working okay for me except date pickers and timepickers

Comment: Can you run the snippet above on your local machine? If so, I think that implies a problem with the way this code is integrated into your app. Maybe check that the `id="datepicker-from"` in your HTML matches the element in your javascript when you call `$("#datepicker-from").datepicker()`...